# cannot get EvaluationMonitor to output number of iterations taken to find a root

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, evaluation, iteration

I was given the following problem:

*Consider the equation x = exp(-x2). Plot the two curves on the same plot to get a rough idea of the intersection point. Then use a built - in function (e.g. FindRoot or FixedPoint or Solve) to find the solution to 100 significant digits and use the option "EvaluationMonitor" to find out how many iterations Mathematica took.*

I was able to solve it except for the number of iterations it took to solve it.

1. Why isn't it giving me the number of iterations it took to solve it?
2. How do I fix it?

The following is my input and output:

```
In[42]:= f = x
g = Exp[-x^2]
Block[{c = 0}, {FindRoot[f == g, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
   EvaluationMonitor -> c++], c}]

Out[42]= x

Out[43]= E^-x^2

Out[44]= {{x -> 
   0.65291864041920471553508076735319636992011688110299773062492149407\
50472761980389255118225716068055969}, 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use :> (`RuleDelayed`) not -> (`Rule`) for the monitors:

```
f = x;
g = Exp[-x^2];
Block[{steps = 0, funEval = 0, jacEval = 0, res},
 res = FindRoot[f == g, {x, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> funEval++, 
   StepMonitor :> steps++, 
   Jacobian -> {Automatic, EvaluationMonitor :> jacEval++}];
 Print["Function Evaluations: ", funEval];
 Print["Steps: ", steps];
 Print["Jacobian Evaluations: ", jacEval];
 res
 ]
```

(*
Function Evaluations: 8
Steps: 6
Jacobian Evaluations: 0

{x -> 0.652919}
*)